# prereqs-ubuntu.sh and npm install -g

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger-composer

I'm closely following the tutorial for installing a development environment in Linux.

1 - I tried to install the prerequisite programs using a non-sudo user and failed because it requires a sudo user to run. Ok, so maybe the prerequisites can be executed in sudo, just not the Composer. So I ran the prerequisites using a sudo user without any issues.

2 - Now I switched to a non-sudo user to run the Composer install. So I did "npm install -g composer-cli" and it failed because npm is not installed. I looked at this reference, https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions. Is this right? Is there a specific option to use. I tried option 2 and it didn't quite work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you follow all of the pre-reqs from https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html ? I only mention, because you wrote `and it failed because npm is not installed.`. This would mean you didn't install npm yet (and therefore your question on permissions is an entirely separate question, that may not be an issue once you have npm installed.

In the prereqs-ubuntu.sh script it mentions (after nvm / node install):

```
*# Configure nvm to use version 6.9.5
nvm use 6.9.5
nvm alias default 6.9.5*

**# Install the latest version of npm
npm install npm@latest -g**
```

To resolve your particular problem, you would run the last line.

Only use sudo *where instructed* in the pre-reqs-ubuntu.sh script.  To re-iterate - do not install Hyperledger Composer packages - with sudo. It will cause problems, for npm (when using it for installs) and won't install properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did and managed through:

--> install nodejs and npm:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=8
```

so you get the latest node8.

--> then to solve "sudo" problem with node specify the npm prefix:

```
npm config set prefix ~/.node_modules
```

add the following to .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$PATH
```

Now the packages will install into your user directory and no permissions will be harmend.

--> install nvm (to get exactly node 8.9 version on the next step):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

*or*

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

Verify:

```
node -v nvm
```

which should output 'nvm' if the installation was successful.

--> get and set node 8.9 version:

```
nvm install v8.9.0 
nvm use 8.9.0
```

--> reset PATHes:
echo export PATH="$HOME/npm/b

```
in:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
npm config set prefix ~/npm
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/$USER/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

--> reset PATHs:

```
echo export PATH="$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
npm config set prefix ~/npm
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/$USER/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

--> at this stage the docker previous setup shall be destroyed:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)
```

--> now you can install Fabric dev. env. (assuming the rest of prereq components stand available (Docker, Docker Compose, Python, git)):

```
npm install -g composer-cli
```

*etc.*